# Calcular tiempos desde n registros anteriores en pandas

Tags: python

Trabajo con Python 3.5 y Pandas 0.19.2
Os describo mi problema:
Tengo en un data frame diferentes idactivos ordenados por fecha y hora de forma ascendente.
Pues bien, tengo un campo llamado Resultado cuyo valores son NaN ó 1.
Necesito calcular para cada fila cuanto tiempo hace que se dió la N última vez en que el campo resultado fue 1 para ese idactivo concreto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí os pongo el código de mi proyecto:

```html
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'IdActivo': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                   'Fecha': ['1990-01-02','1990-01-03','1990-01-04','1990-01-05','1990-01-08',\
                                  '1990-01-09','1990-01-10','1990-01-11','1990-01-12' ,'1990-01-15',\
                                  '1990-01-16', '1990-01-17', '1990-01-18','1990-01-19','1990-01-22',\
                                  '1990-01-23 ', '1990-01-24', '1990-01-25','1990-01-26','1990-01-29'],
                   'Hora': ['10:10:00','10:11:00','10:12:00','10:13:00','10:10:00',\
                                  '10:10:00','10:17:00','10:14:00','11:14:00','12:14:00',\
                                  '10:10:00', '10:20:00', '14:22:00','15:22:00','16:22:00',\
                                  '10:10:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00','00:00:00','00:00:00']})
def Inicio():
    numHoraDia = '10:10:00'
    numDia = 2  # para nosotros el 2 será el martes ya que le añadimos +1 al lunes que es 0 por defecto
    nomDiasSemanaHora = "  Resultado";    inpfield = "Fecha" ;    oupfield = "Dia_Semana"

    df_final = Fecha_Dia_Hora(df,inpfield,oupfield,numHoraDia,numDia,nomDiasSemanaHora)
    print (df_final)


def Fecha_Dia_Hora(df, inpfield, oupfield,numHoraDia,numDia,nomDiasSemanaHora):
    ord_df = df.sort_values(by=['IdActivo', 'Fecha'])
    ord_df[inpfield] = pd.to_datetime(ord_df[inpfield])  # Esta línea pone el campo nuevo 'inpfield' a tipo class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'
    ord_df[oupfield] = ord_df[inpfield].dt.dayofweek + 1  # Resultados: 0=Lunes, 1=Martes... 4=Viernes Le he añadido un 1 para que empiece por 1=Lunes.....
    ord_df[nomDiasSemanaHora] = np.NaN
    ord_df.ix[np.logical_and(ord_df[oupfield] == numDia, ord_df.Hora == numHoraDia), [nomDiasSemanaHora]] = '1'
    return ord_df.sort_index()

def Fin():
    print("FIN")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Inicio()
    Fin()
```

Más detalle en la siguiente imagen:

¿Alguna idea sobre cómo podría darle forma?.

Gracias de antemano.
Charo

Comment: Alguien me podría ayudar con este ejemplo de dataframe que tengo a realizar lo siguiente.

Comment: Alguien me podría ayudar con este ejemplo de dataframe que tengo a realizar lo siguiente: Hacer dataframes cargando  sólo las filas que tienen el mismo IdActivo para así poder realizar los cálculos que deseo sobre el dataframe nuevo. Se harán tantos dataframe como IdActivos distintos hayan. Al final de cada cálculo del dataframe nuevo quisiera volcar los datos dentro del dataframe principal.  Yo he intentado utilizar la función groupby pero no me sale. A ver si me podeis ayudar.